# Expected End of Statement

Tags: excel, vba

Ok, I have used a formula that was suggested that works well, should work without an issue but now I am getting this error:

> Expected End of Statement

Here is the formula

```
 Range("B4").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="T",VLOOKUP(RC[7],treatlookup,11,FALSE),VLOOKUP(RC[7],itemlookup,22,FALSE))"
```

Not sure what is going on, why it is happening.  Any suggestions.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the embedded double-quotes (`"T"`) by doubling them (`""T""`):

```
Range("B4").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=""T"",VLOOKUP(RC[7],treatlookup,11,FALSE),VLOOKUP(RC[7],itemlookup,22,FALSE))"
                                      ^^^
                                       |
                                      Here
```

Excel is trying to pair the opening quote at `"=IF` with the next double-quote it finds, which is at `"T"`, and that portion (`"=IF(RC[-1]="`) isn't a valid statement. Doubling them tells Excel to consider them separately, allowing them to be embedded in the formula correctly.

(The error is highlighted for you when you get the message, if you look at the code it's indicating; that's how I spotted it.)

Comment: @SASUSMC So to fix the issue, wrap the `T` in double quotes. `""T""`

Comment: Thanks, for the help. Always get confused on the single/ double quote item.

Comment: @KenWhite Single quotes don't work; [they throw an error.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787594/formula-application-defined-or-object-defined-error/21787658#21787658)

Comment: ARich: Right you are. I tested by compiling before posting, but didn't actually run the macro. I'll correct. Thanks.